# Android - Overlap two textviews

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout

I have two TextViews in a LinearLayout. I set a negative padding on the lower one to bump it up (using TextView.setPadding). On both of them I did setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.transparent), hoping this would let them show through each other.

The result:

[image: fun]

I'd like the 'f' in 'fun' to show up completely - I don't mind if the text actually overlaps. I don't know if the TextView is clipping it or if the upper TextView is covering it up or both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `TextView` `android:background="#00000000"` 
That will give your `TextView` a transparent background. 
The `#00000000` is a hexadecimal color in the order of Alpha, Red, Blue, Green. Like so:

```
#AARRGGBB
```

Also - I think its the padding, and not the other text field that is clipping. Try using a negative `android:layout_marginTop` instead.

Comment: Yep, using a margin instead of padding did the trick. Thanks!