# How to place a TextView behind another TextView?

Tags: android

I want to put a TextView overlapping another TextView in android studio, how should I do it?

Im using fontawesome as text and I want to put some text on top of the icon.

Also I didnt find any question regarding this.

Im not an expert in android studio, so sorry if im missing something.

Comment: can you post an expected output ?

Comment: Like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719155/android-overlap-two-textviews

Answer (score 1):

When you place both `TextView` to a `RelativeLayout`, the last defined one covers the first one.. so the first `TextView` appears behind the second   `TextView` ..is it usable in your case?

Answer (score 1):

Simply wrap your `TextView`s in either `<FrameLayout`> or `<RelativeLayout>`. Note the order matters here and the one you want on top should be the last one in your view group.

```
<FrameLayout>
   <TextView "bottom one">
   <TextView "top one">
</FrameLayout>
```